# Get indices of all columns that are factors of a data.frame

Tags: r

Is there any nice way to get directly the indices of all columns that are `factor`s in a `data.frame`?

So far, I am stuck with:

```
sapply(df, is.factor)
```

Comment: use it with which: which(sapply(df, is.factor))

Comment: Why do you want indices? Normally the logical vector is sufficient.

Comment: @droopy works like charm; I was not expecting this to work. It's such a nice and easy solution.

Comment: @hadley I ignore those columns by index later in my calculation....

Comment: You don't need to use an index, just use not (`!`)

Comment: @droopy, could you make that an answer so Dennis can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by @droopy (in the comments to my question):

```
 which(sapply(df, is.factor))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars
df$vs <- as.factor(df$vs)
df$gear <- as.factor(df$gear)
str(df)
```

`vs` and `gear` are of class `factor` now. 
Now input the variablenames into `sapply`. `x` now iterates over every column-name and uses the specified function, eg. `is.factor(df[, x])`

```
sapply(colnames(df), function(x) is.factor(df[, x]))
  mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The result will be a `TRUE/FALSE` vector.

```
which(sapply(colnames(df), function(x) is.factor(df[, x])))
  vs gear 
   8   10
```

gives you the indices.

Comment: Okay. Now i see that this answer is overly complicated. But why give a -1 for it? It does what you wanted....